# SQL Error: ORA-00904: invalid identifier (Foreign key)

Tags: database, oracle

Can't find the mistake in:

```
ALTER TABLE REZERVACIJA
ADD CONSTRAINT REZERVACIJA_KAMBARYS_FK1 FOREIGN KEY(KAMBARIO_NUMERIS)
REFERENCES KAMBARYS(KAMBARIO_NUMERIS)
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: What have you done to try to find the mistake? Just so that the obvious can be ruled out ...

Comment: I search for solution in books, internet..but i cant find the answer

Comment: How does your table `KAMBARYS` look like? Is `KAMBARIO_NUMERIS` it's primary key?

Comment: Please post your definitions of the tables `KAMBARYS` and `REZERVACIJA`. I would guess the error is somewhere in there.

Comment: REATE TABLE KAMBARYS
(KAMBARIO_NUMERIS  varchar(10) NOT NULL , 
KAMBARIO_AUKSTAS varchar(10) NOT NULL, 
KAMBARIO_KAINA NUMBER(3,2) NOT NULL, 
KAMBARIU_SKAICIUS varchar(1) NOT NULL, 
KITA_INFORMACIJA varchar(100));

Comment: CREATE TABLE REZERVACIJA
(REZERVACIJOS_KODAS  varchar(10) NOT NULL, 
DATA_NUO DATE NOT NULL, 
DATA_IKI DATE NOT NULL);

Comment: It doesn't look like KAMBARIO_NUMERIS is a column in REZERVACIJA table, but you are trying to use it as a foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

According to the DDL in your comments, shouldn't it be:

```
ALTER TABLE REZERVACIJA
ADD CONSTRAINT REZERVACIJA_KAMBARYS_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (REZERVACIJOS_KODAS)
REFERENCES KAMBARYS(KAMBARIO_NUMERIS)
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```